# « Noyer le poisson » dans un flot d'air, puis cueillir : séquence de la noyade au figuré, connotation ?

Tags: expressions, étymologie, zoologie, connotation

On a l'expression « [noyer le poisson](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=noyer%20le%20poisson&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnoyer%20le%20poisson%3B%2Cc0) », attestée au propre en 1888 (DHLF/Rey) ou [avant](https://books.google.com/books?id=EMvMcS_0o3YC&dq=%22noyer%20le%20poisson%22&pg=PA547#v=onepage&q=%22noyer%20un%20poisson%22&f=false) (1868) dans le contexte de la pêche pour « [f]atiguer le poisson pris à l'hameçon pour le sortir plus facilement de l'eau », puis au figuré, pour « [c]réer la confusion, embrouiller les choses pour éluder une question, donner le change, tromper quelqu'un. ». Par ailleurs on note aussi, indépendamment de la pêche, mais toujours au figuré, *noyer qqn sous un flot (de paroles)* pour « [é]tourdir quelqu'un en parlant beaucoup » (TLFi, [noyer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/noyer) ; voir aussi [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/noyer/55155/locution)) et on donne une partie de l'extrait suivant :

> [...] Ne plaidez jamais en pur esprit comme si vous étiez devant la
>   justice juste. Au contraire faites saillir le motif ou l'argument
>   spécial à l'homme qui va faire l'arrêt. Tel ancien avoué est sensible
>   à des raisons de procédure, tel auteur de livres se rend aux
>   considérations générales, tel autre est clérical ou libéral, bon
>   vivant ou mari trompé. Touchez cette corde. **[** Le procédé le plus
>   universel est de fatiguer le juge, de ***le*** noyer sous un flot de
>   raisonnements contraires, de lui faire pied, de l'entraîner dans le
>   déluge des interprétations, des citations, des autorités puis, à la
>   fin, dans la dernière réplique, de lui tendre la perche. C'est-à-dire
>   un gros argument bien clair définitif auquel il se raccroche. **]**
>
> [ [Hippolyte Taine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippolyte_Taine), [Notes sur Paris. Vie et opinions de M.
>   Frédéric-Thomas Graindorge](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notes_sur_Paris._Vie_et_opinions_de_M._Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric-Thomas_Graindorge) (1867), [p. 303](https://archive.org/stream/notessurparisvie00tain#page/302/mode/2up/), je souligne, marque ]

Généralement, on peut faire un certain parallèle entre la description bien usuelle de la technique servant à *noyer un poisson* de 1868 et le propos de Taine ici, en termes de séquence du moins, avec l'idée de *tendre la perche* (une *perche* n'est pas une *épuisette*, mais quand même) à la fin de l'action. En plus, on n'a pas la forme pronominale, comme on avait eu auparavant (*se noyer dans les détails*, Balzac 1831, ... *dans une goûte d'eau*, Bossuet ; *se noyer dans les explications*, 18<sup>e</sup> chez Voltaire entre autres) ; le sens figuré s'élabore sur l'idée d'être *submergé*, de *perdre pied*. Une partie des sens au figuré du verbe noyer ont une valeur péjorative, particulièrement en art avec un sens proche de celui de *diluer*, et s'élaborent sur l'idée de rendre *indiscernable*, *incompréhensible*. On atteste enfin *noyer le poisson* dans ces derniers sens, et celui de *s'en tirer par des paroles confuses*, en 1932 (éléments tirés du *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, dir. A. Rey, ed. *Le Robert*). Le *TLFi* ne semble pas se prononcer sur l'origine de la noyade du poisson au figuré, mais donne l'exemple :

> Il est naturellement incertain, et son art est de faire passer son
>   incertitude pour politique. Il noie le poisson par hésitation et
>   inconsistance.
>
> [ [Montherland](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_de_Montherlant), *Reine morte*, 1942. ]

où l'idée de tromperie y semble absente à première vue et le poisson, plutôt générique.

---

- L'extrait de Taine entre crochets ne constitue-t-il pas la définition
  même de *noyer le poisson* ; *noyer quelqu'un sous un flot*
  quelconque, n'est-ce en fait qu'une partie de la séquence de l'action
  de *noyer le poisson* ; est-ce étourdir ou plutôt asphyxier ; le segment ou l'expression ont-ils une connotation péjorative ?
- *Noyer le poisson* implique-t-il une idée de tromperie ou de mesquinerie ; est-ce péjoratif ou est-ce un art ; l'était-ce dans le propos de Montherland ?
- Où atteste-t-on en premier, et directement, *noyer le poisson* (au figuré, autour de 1932) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'extrait de Taine entre crochets ne correspond pas exactement à *noyer le poisson*.

Noyer quelqu'un sous un flot de quelque chose signifie leur donner plus de cette chose qu'ils ne peuvent en prendre. Ce n'est pas forcément péjoratif : par exemple on peut dire d'une armée qu'elle noie son ennemi sous un déluge de feu, ce qui dénoterait la supériorité de cette armée.

Noyer le poisson implique une idée de dissimulation, d'esquive. C'est potentiellement péjoratif selon le contexte - si l'esquive est une manifestation d'incompétence ou motivée par le désir de tromper par exemple - mais pas forcément: il peut être bon de noyer le poisson pour dévier le cours d'une conversation dangereuse, par ex "Il m'a demandé si mon frère a une copine - j'ai noyé le poisson, je n'avais pas envie de lui dire qu'il est homosexuel"

Comment: Merci ! Si un moment donné on a une idée pour l'attestation de 1932 ça pourrait faire un bon complément.